# question about counting time calculated by property

Tags: python, django, properties, sum, timedelta

I have created a date and time delta property. this property calculates the total time between two date and times for a job. Now I want to create a property that sums all the time of the jobs and represents it on a card. I have tried many ,but no success. Hopefully someone has a solution

```
@property
def Get_time_diference(self):
    start_time = self.date
    end_time = self.dateTo
    total =  end_time - start_time
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making "total" an attribute of the class

```
class TimeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total =0

    @property
    def Get_time_diference(self):
        start_time = self.date
        end_time = self.dateTo
        diff = end_time - start_time
        self.total+=diff
        return diff

    def get_total(self):
        return self.total
```

Another solution could be using global

```
global total
total=0

@property
def Get_time_diference(self):
    start_time = self.date
    end_time = self.dateTo
    diff = end_time - start_time
    total+=diff
    return diff
```